# Adding an Object to Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs

For some reason I can't get this to work. 
I want to add new scores to a reducer field called `scoreList`

but it doesn't seem to append the new object to the `scoreList`. Instead, it replaces the list with the object:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { scoreList:[]};

 export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
         case ADD_SCORE:
            return {...state, scoreList: {...state.scoreList, ...action.payload}}

    }
    return state;
}
```

How can I make it so that ADD_SCORE will append a score to the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update it as array. Do like this.
if `action.payload` is a single object.

```
return {...state, scoreList: [...state.scoreList, action.payload]}
```

if `action.payload` is array of objects.

```
return {...state, scoreList: [...state.scoreList, ...action.payload]}
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a way that i can push the action.payload to the front of the list?

Comment: yes you can do that, `return {...state, scoreList: [action.payload, ...state.scoreList]}
`

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an object instead of an array. At least I'm assuming it's supposed to be an array from what you said:

```
scoreList: [...state.scoreList, ...action.payload]
```

If action.payload is a single item then omit the `...` from in front of it.